# css div not able to be displayed above other

Tags: css, border, z-index

I essentially have two div tags I'm dealing with.  On this page - www.employeratlas.com/search.html - when you click on any of the four tabs that tab has a border around it.  The idea is that the border is black on the left, right, and top, and is white on the bottom to cover up the border of the div below it.  This works fine in everything but IE6 and IE7 (IE6 example here http://www.employeratlas.com/images/ie_tabs.png).  I've tried setting the z-index to make the top tab above the other, but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 2):

IE has a different interpretation of `z-index`, taking into consideration parent elements' z-indexes. In essence, it's not possible to elevate an element above its parent's `z-index`.

- [Background info on quirksmode.org](http://www.quirksmode.org/bugreports/archives/2006/01/Explorer_z_index_bug.html)
- [An example of working around it](http://brenelz.com/2009/02/03/squish-the-internet-explorer-z-index-bug/)